рп команда для бота в телеграмм библиотека aiogram
получилось вот это
'''
@dp.message(Command('obnyat'))
async def obnyat(message: types.Message):
    replied_to_message = message.reply_to_message
    if replied_to_message and replied_to_message.from_user:
        await message.answer(f'@{replied_to_message.from_user.username} обнял @{message.from_user.username}')`введите сюда код`

'''
но оно работает только на английском + только с / а я хочу без этого чтобы по сообщению обнять выдавалось команда, можете помочь? aiogram 3.5 если что, всем заранее спасибо

я сделал, теперь другой вопрос как сделать так чтобы он мог читать только первое слово потипу обнять

К примеру так string.split()[0]‍♀️ или так string.startswith("обнять")

Можно использовать магический фильтр F.text
@dp.message(F.text=='обнять')
async def obnyat(message: types.Message):
    replied_to_message = message.reply_to_message
    if replied_to_message and replied_to_message.from_user:
        await message.answer(f'@{replied_to_message.from_user.username} обнял @{message.from_user.username}')

